# Write a Custom Status Check for Upstart

Tags: upstart

I have an Upstart file to launch a daemon.  I don't know how many times it forks and when I last tried to experiment to figure that out, upstart wedged hard and I had to power-cycle the system.

Ideally, I could ask Upstart to simply check a PID file, but the developers, in their infinite wisdom, appear to have removed that option.

Can I write a custom stanza that instructs Upstart to check a PID file?  Simple health check:

```
ps -p `cat /var/run/service/service.pid` >/dev/null
```

If that exits 0, process is still alive.  If it exits non-zero, process is dead ...

Comment: No, you can't. You'll have to write a sysv init script if you want it do custom things. And I find it strange that you'd give up after one failed experiment and jump to custom stanzas.

Comment: Thanks, @muru.  When iterating over a config file requires me to remote-power cycle the server, I back off pretty quick.

Comment: but we are talking of a grant total of three experiments max. Either it's `expect fork`, `expect daemon`, or no expect stanza at all.

Comment: That is three more times to log in to the PDU to toggle power to the server than one encounters from any other system.

Comment: then use a VM. Surely you test your configuration before applying it?